# c3js donut / pie chart - arc fills chart when data value is small compared to other data values

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I'm using c3js charts and having problems with a donut/pie chart.

One data value is very small compared to the others in the chart and this is causing the arc to fill the chart completely.

This is a simple example that has the issue:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ['data1', 1000000000],
            ['data2', 1],
        ],
        type: 'pie'
    }
});
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahill/44yha98s/10/

data2 is filling the chart, whereas it should be data1 that fills it.

Decreasing the value of data1 'fixes' it so it's something to do with the ratio between the two data items.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You sure? It's 'data1' that rightly fills up the pie for me (google chrome)

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with Chrome but OK on Firefox...which browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry...which platform?  I'm on Linux.

Comment: Latest chrome version on windows (53). It's the same in Opera and Firefox for me too. You might have just have something cached. Try a hard reload (CTRL + f5)? Edit: Now I see you're on linux, but try it anyways

Comment: Many thanks for the info....just seems to be an issue with Chrome 53.0.2785.92 on Linux (even in incognito).  All good on Mac.....haven't tried Windows.